# How can i convert this lists object into a dataframe?

Tags: python, html, pandas, parsing, stringio

I have something which lokos like (called lines)

```
['                id\t    Name\t    Type\t      User\t     Q\t             country\t       Final-score\t       Progress\t                       website',
 'abcde\t                 jen\t      engineer\t  jenabc\t           RUNNING\t         UK\t             75%\t                                N/A',
 'fres\t        Penny\t               dr\t     dr123\t           RUNNING\t         DENMARK\t             67%\t                                N/A']
```

each line which is in the speech marks and separated by ',' is a dataframe row. However i cannot convert to dataframe.

```
new_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(",".join(lines[1:])),sep = "\t")
```

i do [1:] since the first line is just a comment. i get the error: `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 963 fields in line 3, saw 1099`

i'd like my datframe to be such that the first row is the headers, and the rest are the contents separated by \t. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("\n".join(lines)), sep=r"\s+")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      id   Name      Type    User        Q  country Final-score  Progress  website
0  abcde    jen  engineer  jenabc  RUNNING       UK         75%       NaN      NaN
1   fres  Penny        dr   dr123  RUNNING  DENMARK         67%       NaN      NaN
```

Comment: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 11 fields in line 5, saw 12 < -- i get this. i just provided a sample earlier

Comment: @Maths12 Try `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("\n".join(lines)), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine="python")`

Comment: what does sep=r"\s{2,}" mean>

Comment: @Maths12 It's regular expression. It means that the separator is at minimum 2 whitespace characters long.

Comment: actually this doesn't work for me i have values in different columns e.g. one value should be in col1 but in col2. how can i clear the whitespace in the above?